# Taking multiple scans in C

Tags: c

this may be a silly question but is there a way for me to scan in multiple inputs for example I scan one key which then runs through traverse_search, after that, it takes another scan to perform the same task. At the moment it is only able to take 1 scan, performing the task only once.

*Note MAXLEN = 128

```
void list_search(list_t* list, FILE* outFile){
    char key[MAXLEN + 1];
    while(scanf("%129[^\n]", key)){
        traverse_search(list, key, outFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop can easily turn into an *infinite* loop, if there's an error (for example the user presses the end-of-file key sequence).

Comment: As for your problem, do you mean you want to use multiple `scanf` format specifiers, like is possible for `printf`? Well that's possible for `scanf` as well. For example to scan for two integers use e.g. `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)`.

Comment: With that said, I recommend you forget that plain `scanf` exists, and use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)  to read a full line, and then use `sscanf` to parse the line. Also, pay close attention to what `sscanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Oh and another major problem with your current `scanf` call and the `%[]` format specifier: It will not skip leading white-space. So if you used `scanf` earlier it might have left the newline in the input buffer, and that will be the first character read by the shown `scanf`, which means it will stop reading immediately. *And* not remove the newline, so the very next call again there's a leading newline in the input buffer.

Comment: You should add a space before the `%` to filter the previous newline left in the input buffer. And compare `scanf` with the actual number of required items (becuase `EOF` is `true`). So `while(scanf(" %129[^\n]", key) == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing has to do how `scanf` read the input buffer.

With your current format string, `scanf` reads at most 129 characters (or when it encounters a newline `\n`) into the `key` array.

This means that the next character in the input buffer is `\n`. On the second call to `scanf`, the first character in the input buffer is a newline and the scanning will fail and `scanf` return 0 (and the loop exits).

If we assume that the user will only type one newline at the end of the input, you could add a call to `getc` in your code and discard the read value.

```c
void list_search(list_t* list, FILE* outFile){
    char key[MAXLEN + 1];
    getc(stdin); // read the newline and hope the next character is not a newline again
    while(scanf("%129[^\n]", key)){
        traverse_search(list, key, outFile);
    }
}
```

**Please not that your code does not handle EOF**. When hit with an EOF on the standard input, your code will loop forever (in case of EOF, `scanf` return EOF, usually -1).

I would strongly advise to use a more robust way of scanning and validating the input, such as with `getline` and `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

**Code never consumes `'\n'`**

`scanf("%129[^\n]", key)` returns 0 on the 2nd call as it fails to scan in `'\n'`, left over from the first line of user input.

Lead with a `" "` in the format to consume all optional leading white-space including the prior line's `'\n'`.

Even better, look to `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input and avoid `scanf()` until you understand why it is bad.

**Off-by-one**

To read a max length of 128, use `"%128[^\n]"`.

**Test for success**

`while(scanf("%129[^\n]", key))` loops when `scanf()` returns 1 or `EOF`.  Instead, loop on success.

```
// while(scanf("%129[^\n]", key))
while(scanf("%129[^\n]", key) == 1)
```

---

```
void list_search(list_t* list, FILE* outFile){
  char key[MAXLEN + 1];
  //           v--- consume optional leading white-space including prior \n
  while(scanf(" %128[^\n]", key) == 1) {
    traverse_search(list, key, outFile);
  }
}
```